# Get Text Value of `a` element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the text values of some `a` elements using jquery selectors, but I seem to be having issues. If I use .val() I get nothing, and if I use .text() they have an extra return and whitespace.

Here's the element whose text values I need:

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle langLocaleNameSelector"
                    data-toggle="dropdown">en_US<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
```

First off, I'm trying to write a selector that selects only the elements where the innerText does not equal "LangLocale".

I tried doing that this way:

```
var selectors = $('a.langLocaleNameSelector[innerText!="LangLocale"]');
```

But it seems to pull in all of them anyway.

Then, if I try to call .text() off of those selectors, I get something like:

```
"en_US [return]          en_CA [return]            "
```

When what I really want is an array of their innerTexts, something like this:

```
['en_US', 'en_CA']
```

Can anyone tell me A. how to write the proper selector to get only the ones I want, and B. how to get just the innerText from that element once I have it?

Comment: What exactly is LangLocale? Your a element doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: Maybe split by [return]? I assume [return] is really backslash n but SO strips it out? After you split you'll have the array. Then map it to trim?

Comment: @arknave It's the displayed text. In my example, it is "en_US".

Comment: The carriage return and white space is valid; it's what is in the element. If you don't want it, you'll have to trim it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this -

```
var elems = $('a.langLocaleNameSelector').filter(function () {
     return $.trim($(this).text()) !== "LangLocale";
});
```

To get array of inner texts -

```
var arr = $('a.langLocaleNameSelector').filter(function () {
     return $.trim($(this).text()) !== "LangLocale";
}).map(function () {
     return $.trim($(this).text());
}).get();
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/WCp2b/3/

Comment: +1... I would also add that it would be preferable in my opinion not to use the innerText as the value, instead i would use a data attribute like `data-value` then you dont have to worry about the trim, and if you want to change the labeling presented to the user you can do so without changing any of the code that will eventually "consume" the locale value.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the filter did not return any of them at all. I did discover that I could just access the `element.text` property and that contains the value I want, though, without having to trim it.

Comment: Alright, it definitely works. I figured out a way it can be simplified a bit though. You can use `$(this).text` instead of `$.trim($(this).text())`. Do you think there's anything wrong with directly accessing the text field like that?

Comment: @CorayThan Do you mean `$(this).text()` without trim, Yes it could work but if you have got something like this `" LangLocale "` , that will fail, you need to trim the white spaces then,

Comment: No, I mean not calling the jquery `.text()`, and rather accessing the `text` field of that element.

Comment: @CorayThan You can't do this `$(this).text` or `this.text` , But you can do this `--->` `this.innerText`

Answer (score 1):

The carriage return and white space is valid and correct; it's what is in the element - you have a carriage return plus a whole load of white space right there in the HTML. If you don't want it, you'll have to trim it off.

Or you could close up the space at the end of the `<a>` element, so that the `</a>` is immediately after the end of the content so that there's no white space in it.

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle langLocaleNameSelector"
                data-toggle="dropdown">en_US<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

The other alternative would be to put the relevant part of the content of the `<a>` element into an inner element that doesn't have any white space.

en_US

... and then select that new inner element instead of the `<a>`.

Comment: Do you mean the return after the class is causing the return, or the `<span>` element is causing it?

Comment: After the `<span>`, you have a return. On the next line, you have a bunch of white space before it gets to the `</a>`. That return and white space are part of the element's text value, and are what is being given to you when you call `.text()`.

Comment: Ohhh, yeah, now I see it. Oops. :)

Answer (score 1):

In POJS you could do this

HTML

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle langLocaleNameSelector" data-toggle="dropdown">en_US<span class="caret"></span></a>

<a class="btn dropdown-toggle langLocaleNameSelector" data-toggle="dropdown">LangLocale<span class="caret"></span></a>

<a class="btn dropdown-toggle langLocaleNameSelector" data-toggle="dropdown">en_UK<span class="caret"></span></a>

<a class="btn dropdown-toggle langLocaleNameSelector" data-toggle="dropdown">en_CA<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Javascript

```
var arrayOfTexts = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.getElementsByClassName("langLocaleNameSelector"), function (array, langLocaleNameSelector) {
    var text = langLocaleNameSelector.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    if (text !== "LangLocale") {
        array.push(text);
    }

    return array;
}, []);

console.log(arrayOfTexts);
```

Output

```
["en_US", "en_UK", "en_CA"]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/8QaY4/)

Which in jquery syntax could be

Javascript

```
var arrayOfTexts = $(".langLocaleNameSelector").filter(function () {
    return this.childNodes[0].nodeValue !== "LangLocale";
}).map(function () {
    return this.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}).toArray();

console.log(arrayOfTexts);
```

Output

```
["en_US", "en_UK", "en_CA"]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kkhNm/)